# How can I make a Wordpress plugin that can convert any page Gutenberg to Elementor and Elementor to Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

Sometimes, in Wordpress I need to transfer some pages from Elementor page builder to Gutenberg block. Most of the time this task is very hard and we does not achieve the proper output.
I know, it won't be easy to do and maybe no one explain me the full process to make it. If anyone give me just a hint for this idea that will help me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: There is a WordPress SE where this might already be answered. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ StackOverflow is primarily a site for asking questions about code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a code generator for your plugin. that takes some data from the user and provide control for him. maybe it could be a solution. But for complex widgets or blocks, you will fail to generate code for this.